# What is the right way to load a package main class?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've imported a very simple project packaged in the following way :

[image]

I would like to run the Main.java in the package test

This is obviously a ClassPath type of problem, but I would like to know what would be the cleanest way to run the Main.java located in the test package.

Comment: how is the complete path? is your directory marked as a sources root?

Comment: Something like this /Users/my_username/Documents/folder1/sgbd/

Comment: The creator of this project sent it without a src folder, so I supposed he had a way to run this main class without a src. I'm not quite sure about this

Comment: basically, you run a professional IDE without knowing about the basics of it? does the "creator of this project" use an IDE?

Comment: You have imported a sub-directory instead of the project directory. The line `package sgbd.test;` means that `Main.java` have to be located in `sgbd/test` in a source folder, but it is in `test` which is not a source folder and will therefore not be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue:

The **J** symbol you see over your `Main.java` file indicates that the particular java file is not the part of your source code, this is the reason you are not able to compile it and run it using eclipse.

[image]

one quick solution is to Move your java files into the `src` folder which is immediately inside the project's folder.

Comment: there is no src folder there.

Comment: he should create one. IDEs like eclipse has strong relationship among directory structures.

Comment: he should run it like the author did, without an IDE

Comment: That is with the command prompt obviously. but creating a `src` folder inside the project is not much of a pain.

Comment: it will take more than just that, he has to decently organize and package the entire project.

Comment: @Stultuske He? [_"Prefer gender-neutral language when uncertain."_](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: Ultimately, what I ended up doing is moving every single folder to a package under the src folder newly created.

Comment: I was hoping to find a more automatic way to do a simple thing like this through Eclipse

Comment: @FeatherAndInk Just use _File > Open Projects from File System..._ and choose the right directory to let Eclipse detect and configure your project. Unfortunately, you chose the wrong directory (a package directory) that cannot be used as project directory (which is a restriction of Java, not of Eclipse).